# Why won't mount.cifs use my credential file?

Tags: linux, cifs, network-share

I have a script that needs to mount a Windows share to a Linux box, run a script, then unmount it.  Despite following the man page for mount.cifs the command fails to recognize the credential file.

I made sure file sharing packages were present:

```
sudo yum install samba-client samba-common cifs-utils
```

Created drive that network share will mount to

```
sudo mkdir /share/
```

Created the credential file

```
sudo vim /root/.cifs
```

.cifs file contents

```
username=uname
password=pword
```

Created my .sh file

```
sudo vim /usr/bin/scritp.sh
```

script.sh contents

```
#!bin/bash
mount.cifs //ipaddress/share /share/ -o credentials=/root/.cifs
<script which makes use of the share>
umount /share/
```

Made the script executable

```
sudo chmod u+x /usr/bin/script.sh
```

Tested script

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ./script.sh
```

Despite having the credential file specified, I am still prompted for a password for root user (connecting to Windows share with no "root" user"
Output from running script:

```
Password for root@//ipaddress/share:
```

Can anyone figure out what I have done wrong?  It seems consistent with all documentation I have read.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, modifying the script to the following worked:

```
mount -t cifs -o credentials=/root/.cifs //ipaddress/share /share/
cd /share/
./script.sh
umount /share/
```

Not sure why, since mount -t cifs just invokes mount.cifs, but if you are experiencing the same issue, that's how I finally got around it.